# Laravel 5.4 return error message if user try login without password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I need to show an error like the error when user write a wrong data in the login form when user does not enter his password.
I think the method I should overwrite is validateLogin()

```
    protected function validateLogin()
{

    $this->validate(request(), [
        'email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required'
    ]);
}
```

But it isn't given me the error message in view. 
I got the error when I left email field empty but not when I left password empty

Comment: That happens by default if are using default Laravel auth module.
Are you making a custom login module?

Comment: no I'm using the default auth

Comment: And what you have tried so far in code?

Comment: I tried to overwrite sendFailedLoginResponse() function in my logincontroller but it doesn't help

Comment: If you are using the auth module and hasn't changed anything in those files then that error will be thrown by default.
Both the required one by the html required attribute or if you have deleted that from Inspector the server side error will be thrown, either way that error will be thrown.

Comment: As you said you tried to override the `sendFailedLoginResponse()`, provide the changes you have done.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users  I think this would help 
but how to throw errors?

Comment: That's manual authentication but you said you are using default auth it does that.You said you have tried to override `sendFailedLoginResponse()` so just provide that code we'll see if there're any errors in that.

Comment: After thinking I think validateLogin is the right function to modify. but if still not returning an error message if password is empty 

 protected function validateLogin()
    {

        $this->validate(request(), [
            'email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required'
        ]);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the ValidateLogin Method it was in the view.

```
  @if ($errors->has('email'))
       <span class="help-block" style="margin-top:30px;">
           <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
       </span>
  @endif
```

I was just need to have the same if condition for the password.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller, you can use something like this:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), User::$auth_rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    $remember=$request->has('remember')?true:false;
    $user=User::where('email',$request->get('email'))->first();

    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')), $remember)){
        return Redirect::route('dashboard');        
    }

    return Redirect::route('login')->with('status','Invalid credentials');
```

Hope it helps you.